# astyle did not indent lines ended with . or ->

Tags: c++, coding-style

I tried to use astyle to stylize my code, but when it came to

```
some_structure[some_index].
    method_call(some_parameters);
```

it would turn it into

```
some_structure[some_index].
method_call(some_parameters);
```

I am using --style=ansi. I did not see any corresponding options in help file.

Can you help?

Comment: you should mark it as NSFW or my professor would kill me if he saw the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

astyle can't recognize and indent your code because of the newline, even Uncrustify (http://uncrustify.sourceforge.net/) which has tons of options, can't.

you can use UniversalIndentGUI (http://universalindent.sourceforge.net/) to see the changes live and save a config file for you favorite code beautifier.